# Docker installation without internet (RHEL)

Tags: docker, yum, rhel, self-hosting, docker-ce

I am planning to install Docker CE under RHEL on an offline (Intranet) box.

Please share the procedure how to create repository.

Answer (score 0):

You need to gain access to or set up a self-hosted (local) Yum repository inside your internal network but with access to the internet, sync it with external (public) Yum repos, and add the local Yum repo to your client system's repos list.